# Print part of the int variable in C++

Tags: c++, cout

I declare some variables:

```
int area_code;
int telephone_number;
```

when I get the input from user like:

```
cout << "Enter the area code";
cin >> area_code;
cout << "Enter your local telephone number";
cin >> telephone_number;
```

now when I want to display them, if their phone number is 6152222222 it should be displayed like:

> 615-222-2222

for the first part I can do like:

```
cout << area_code << "-";
```

but I don't know how can I separate them with the dash for that one variable?

Comment: Hint: Use the `/` and `%` operators.

Comment: You are aware that you can't store a 10 digit phone number in an int right?  It's too big, valid phone numbers overflow it.

Comment: Don't store telephone_number or area code as integers as lots have leading zeros.

Comment: @Cicada While I agree, this just moves the problem one step further. Internally, the phone number still needs t be stored, and `int` is still inappropriate (as is *every* other number type).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use math to calculate the area code and the local exchange code for your number:

- `6152222222 / 10000` drops the last four digits, giving you `615222`
- Further dividing by `1000` gives you `615`; taking the remainder of the division by `1000` gives you `222`.

Please note that using an `int` to represent a telephone number limits your ability to store some more exotic phone numbers, such as `1-800-SOMETHING`. Using a class encapsulating a `string` with additional validations may prove to be a better alternative:

```
class phone_number {
string phone;
public:
    phone_number(const string& p) {
        // validate p...
        if (p.size() != 10) {
            // Do something violent here...
            cerr << "The phone number is incorrect." << endl;
        }
        // Validate more things about the number before the assignment...
        phone = p;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const phone_number& p);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const phone_number& pn) {
    const string &p(pn.phone);
    os << "(" << p.substr(0, 3) << ")" << p.substr(3, 3) << "-" << p.substr(6);
    return os;
}

int main() {
    phone_number p = phone_number("6152784567");
    cout << p << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[This produces the expected output on ideone](http://ideone.com/LXuJ2).

Comment: so when I cout to display them again would be like? cout << area_code << first_half_result << whatabout the last 4 digits?

Comment: @Ali The last four digits is the original `number % 10000`.

Comment: int i = 6152222222; // does anyone see the problem with this line

Comment: This is perfect, I guess I should store them in an array? to make this easier?

Comment: @Wug Yes, it does not fit in an `int`. You need t least a `long long` to store US phone numbers.

Comment: @ali: You're using C++, make a class, or even better, find an existing one.

Answer (score 4):

Telephone numbers shouldn't be stored in integer variables. You never know how long a phone number may get, which special characters are needed, whether alphabetic characters are needed, leading zeros, et cetera.

Real solution is to use at least `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [`std::numpunct`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/numpunct):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

struct telephone: std::numpunct<char> {
    char do_thousands_sep() const { return '-'; }
    std::string do_grouping() const { return "\04\03"; }
};

int main() {
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale(std::cout.getloc(), new telephone));
    std::cout << 6152222222ll;
}
```

Output:

```
615-222-2222
```

I still wouldn't recommend this method, unless you have to deal with telephone numbers stored as integers for legacy reasons; using strings is more flexible.

Comment: This still treats phone numbers internally as numbers which they – despite the name – are not.

Comment: @Ecatmur, This is a very good solution eventhough I'm still confuse on how to implement this with mine...

Comment: @ecatmur, the only reason now I use `int` to store the input it just because I'm still thinking on how to split the number from the user input to an array....

Answer (score 0):

Change these to std::string types.  Then use substr operations to get the first three digits, and such.  Use stringstream to get between ints and strings.

And, honestly, if you insist on holding these variables in ints, I would recommend temporarily converting them to strings, and using string operations, to compute the value `xxx-xxxx`, because if you write your own code using `/` and `%`, you're essentially duplicating the work that's been done to you in `<<` and `>>` operations.

Also, bee-tee-dubs, that number doesn't actually fit in a 32 bit signed or unsigned int, which I consider another symptom of using the wrong datatype.

Edited to C++ flavor the strings and string ops instead of C flavor it, since I was thinking in C for some reason.

Comment: @Cicada - was thinking in C for some reason, wrote the answer into C++.

Answer (score -1):

Just divide the input in three different numbers:

```
end = 6152222222 % 10000
middle = 6152222222 / 10000
areaCode = middle / 1000
middle = middle % 10000
```